# Fetch name from active layer

Tags: pyqgis, layers

I'm trying to get the layer name only to use further in a script.

Printing layer in `layer = iface.activeLayer()` yields `<QgsVectorLayer: 'COSTUM LAYER' (ogr)>`.

I would like to use `'COSTUM LAYER'` only. Is it possible to fetch this part only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html) inherits from the [`QgsMapLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html) base class which has a [`name()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.name) method.

So `iface.activeLayer().name()` will get you the display name of the active layer as @RainForest comments.